# Nginx - fastcgi cache not working for rewrite enabled php page

Tags: nginx, php, rewrite, cache, fastcgi

I've been trying to figure out why Im failing to achieve   fastcgi caching for a rewrite rule applied php page.

While all other request wonderfully cache, the  `rewrite ^(.+)/special/?$ /inc/special.php?req=$1 last;`always sent an $upstream_cache_status MISS.

I tried copying the same `fastcgi_cache` parameters for the `*/special/*` page as well. But not working.

Anyone please suggest where this goes wrong.

```
fastcgi_cache_path /etc/nginx/cache/webcache levels=1:2 keys_zone=wbcache:100m inactive=60m;

server {

      server_name example.com www.example.com;
      root /var/www/html;
      index index.php index.html;
      set $skip_cache 0;

 rewrite ^(.+)/special/?$ /inc/special.php?req=$1 last;
 
 location = /inc/special.php { 
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        
       }

 location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args; 
        }
        
 location ~ \.php$ {
       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
       fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
       fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;
       fastcgi_hide_header "Set-Cookie";

       fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";
       fastcgi_cache_use_stale updating error timeout invalid_header http_500;
       fastcgi_cache_lock on;
       fastcgi_cache_valid any 300s;
       fastcgi_cache_bypass $skip_cache;
       fastcgi_no_cache $skip_cache;
       fastcgi_cache wbcache;
       fastcgi_cache_background_update on;
       fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE $content_type;

       add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;      
}

......
............

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `location = /inc/special.php` passes requests directly to `fastcgi` server, therefore there is no caching.

Furthermore, you need to check the HTTP caching headers set by `special.php`. If the HTTP headers do not allow caching, `fastcgi_cache` does not cache the request.

Comment: I removed the `location = /inc/special.php {..` block. now working fine. Thanks